# Are layouts same as ViewGroups?

Tags: android

I'm a bit confused, when I declare a layout in XML, and I call the:

```
R.layout.idname
```

is this considered the ViewGroup?

Comment: Which XML tag did you give that ID to? Almost everything is considered a VIEW rather than a VIEWGROUP.

Comment: Lets say RelativeLayout

Comment: A RelativeLayout can be cast to a ViewGroup yes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the widget you declared inside your layout. For instance you can declare a single `TextView` inside your layout. `TextView`s are views, not `ViewGroup`. If you declare a LinearLayout for instance, it will be a `ViewGroup`. If you take a look to the documentation you can see the direct and indirect subclass of [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

Comment: But when I go FindViewById, and pass in the R.layout.id it won't work for some reason.

Comment: you have to provide a id not a layout to findViewById

Answer (score 1):

> is this considered the ViewGroup?

No, this is the complete layout file.

> Are layouts same as ViewGroups?

No, one is the file. A `ViewGroup` would be any `View` such as a `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc... that holds other `View`s.

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

> A ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called children.)

Comment: How come Android is making a differentiation to R.layout.id and R.id.id?  Aren't these used interchangly in some cases?  For example setContentView uses R.Layout.

Comment: It depends if you need the id of a layout file or of a single `View`.

Comment: Ok, what if the layout itself is a TextView, is it inferred that R.layout.id is same as R.id.id? I mean can I use FindViewById and pass in the R.layout.id?  Just curious.

Comment: Look in your R.java file, you have `public static final class layout {` with ids for your layout files and `public static final class id {` for when you need the view id of a view or ViewGroup

Comment: No, you would need to use the R.id.someId because that tells it to look in the id class of R.java. Otherwise, it will look in the layout class of R.java

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It depends on which xml layout you have given R.layout.idname to.

`TextView`, `ImageView`, `EditText` for examples are NOT viewgroups.

`FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc are considered viewgroups.

A clue is in the name really... viewgroup. a view that can be a grouping of views.

Answer (score 0):

No, Layouts are not same as ViewGroups. While every Layout is a `ViewGroup`, there are ViewGroups that aren't layouts (e.g. `ViewPager`, `ScrollView`). Regarding an XML file in R.layout, it depends on the root element of the XML: if for example it's a `LinearLayout` - you'll be able to cast it to `ViewGroup`, if it's an `ImageView` - it is considered a `View`.

Answer (score 0):

View group: is a combination of views

Layouts: how views should sortup

View group has views inside it, but how the views should be arranged, the arrangement of views is known as layouts.

For examples, linear layout and relative layout are both layout and view group because they have views inside and the arrangement of views in them are known as layouts.